# split url by python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, split

I have this URL:

```
/drive/rayon.productlist.seomenulevel/fh_refpath$003dfacet_1$0026fh_refview$003dlister$0026fh_view_size$003d100$0026fh_reffacet$003dcategories$0026auchan_page_type$003dcatalogue$0026fh_location$003d$00252f$00252f52$00252ffr_FR$00252fdrive_id$00253d993$00252fcategories$00253c$00257b52_3686967$00257d$00252fcategories$00253c$00257b52_3686967_3686326$00257d$00252fcategories$00253c$00257b52_3686967_3686326_3700610$00257d$00252fcategories$00253c$00257b52_3686967_3686326_3700610_3700620$00257d/Capsules$0020$002843$0029/3700620?t:ac=3686967/3700610
```

i want to have 3 last numbers : item[0] = 3700620, item[1]=3686967 and item[2] = 3700610

i tried this

```
one =   url.split('/')[-1]
two =   url.split('/')[-2]
```

the result of the first one is `3700610"`

and the second one  `3700620?t:ac=3686967`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-regex approach would involve using [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) and a bit of splitting:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url) 
>>> number1 = parsed_url.path.split("/")[-1]
>>> number2, number3 = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query)["t:ac"][0].split("/")
>>> number1, number2, number3
('3700620', '3686967', '3700610')
```

Regex approach:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"/(\d+)\?t:ac=(\d+)/(\d+)$", url).groups()
('3700620', '3686967', '3700610')
```

where `(\d+)` are [saving/capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) that match one or more digits, `\?` would match a literal question mark (we need to escape it since it has a special meaning), `$` would match the end of the string.

You can also [name the groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) and produce a dictionary:

```
>>> re.search(r"/(?P<number1>\d+)\?t:ac=(?P<number2>\d+)/(?P<number3>\d+)", url).groupdict()
{'number2': '3686967', 'number3': '3700610', 'number1': '3700620'}
```

Comment: This is why I hate regex. It just looks *messy*. Although it is easy, if you try to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using regex.

```
import re
re.findall('\d+', url)[-3:]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following two should work.

```
url.split('/')[-2].split('=')[1]
url.split('/')[-2].split('?')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
split_list = url.split('/')
third = split_list[-1]
first, second = split_list[-2].split('?t:ac=')
```

Comment: That seems awfully specific to this exact URL